# Testing Laravel Eloquent Relationship

Tags: laravel, testing, eloquent, phpunit

I'd like to know what's the best approach to ensure that my `Activity` model belongs to a `User`.

**Activity.php**

```
...

public function user()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

How can I write a test that ensure that the `Activity` model has that relationship?

Comment: You can use the database like sqlite to test it create user withe the factory and then create an activity attach it to the user after that load the activity and test if it's linked with the created user

Comment: `Activity::find(1)->user`?

Comment: Thx. @Maraboc can you write an answer? I'll give you your points.

Comment: **GIVEN** you use db engine with foreign key constraints, **WHEN** you create your database, **THEN** ensure FK constraint on the `user_id` column ;) And don't test eloquent, no need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem in testing eloquent with the database as source of truth, so you can use the database like sqlite, for speed performances.

To test it create user with the factory and then create an activity attach it to the created user after that load the activity and test if it's linked with the created user.

We are following the pattern of Given, When, Then => **Given** you have u user **When** he create an activity (logged in, create a post ...) **Then** check if the created activity belongs to the given user ;)